# Symfony Event Listener - populate entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, event-listener

Who can give example?
I have the entities `Project` and `Event` - Many Event to one Project, so when status project changes to `'closed_by_client'`, I need to create an Event for this project.

In the controller:

```
$project = $this
    ->getDoctrine()
    ->getManager()
    ->getRepository('ArtelProfileBundle:Project')
    ->find($id);

        $project->setCurrentStatus('closed_by_client');
        $manager->persist($project);
        $manager->flush();
```

Project entity:

```
/**
 * Project.
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="project")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Repository\ProjectRepository")
* @ExclusionPolicy("all")
*/
class Project
{
const STATE_TO_BE_INDEXED_IN_ELA_NOT_APPROVED = 'not_approved';
const STATE_TO_BE_INDEXED_IN_ELA_CLOSED_BY_CLIENT = 'closed_by_client';

use Timestampable;
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @Expose()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="current_status", type="string", length=100, nullable = true)
 * @Expose()
 * @Type("string")
 */
protected $currentStatus = 'not_approved';

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CodeEvents", mappedBy="project", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
protected $events;

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 */
public function PrePersist(){
    if($this->getCurrentStatus() == self::STATE_TO_BE_INDEXED_IN_ELA_CLOSED_BY_CLIENT){
        $event = new CodeEvents();
        $event
            ->setProject($this)
            ->setEvent(self::STATE_TO_BE_INDEXED_IN_ELA_CLOSED_BY_CLIENT)
        ;
    }
}

/**
 * @ORM\PreFlush()
 */
public function PreFlush(){
    if($this->getCurrentStatus() == self::STATE_TO_BE_INDEXED_IN_ELA_CLOSED_BY_CLIENT){
        $event = new CodeEvents();
        $event
            ->setProject($this)
            ->setEvent(self::STATE_TO_BE_INDEXED_IN_ELA_CLOSED_BY_CLIENT)
        ;
    }
}
```

I think that I could maybe do something like this, but entity `Event` not flush in DB:

```
/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 */
public function PrePersist(){
    if($this->getCurrentStatus() == self::STATE_TO_BE_INDEXED_IN_ELA_CLOSED_BY_CLIENT){
        $event = new CodeEvents();
        $event
            ->setProject($this)
            ->setEvent(self::STATE_TO_BE_INDEXED_IN_ELA_CLOSED_BY_CLIENT)
        ;
    }
}

/**
 * @ORM\PreFlush()
 */
public function PreFlush(){
    if($this->getCurrentStatus() == self::STATE_TO_BE_INDEXED_IN_ELA_CLOSED_BY_CLIENT){
        $event = new CodeEvents();
        $event
            ->setProject($this)
            ->setEvent(self::STATE_TO_BE_INDEXED_IN_ELA_CLOSED_BY_CLIENT)
        ;
    }
}
```

I add

```
    /**
 * @ORM\PreFlush()
 */
public function PreFlush(LifecycleEventArgs $event){
    $entityManager = $event->getEntityManager();
    if($this->getCurrentStatus() == self::STATE_TO_BE_INDEXED_IN_ELA_CLOSED_BY_CLIENT){
        $event = new CodeEvents();
        $event
            ->setProject($this)
            ->setEvent(self::STATE_TO_BE_INDEXED_IN_ELA_CLOSED_BY_CLIENT)
        ;
        $entityManager->persist($event);
        $entityManager->flush();
    }
}
```

but when flush entity have error

```
`Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Proxies\__CG__\Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Project::PreFlush() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs, instance of Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreFlushEventArgs given, called in /home/ivan/host/aog-code/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Event/ListenersInvoker.php on line 102 and defined`
```

How to create listener for event - entity Project change status for 'closed_by_client' - create entity Event?

I did not create early event, how to create event for this business logic ?

Comment: You are mixing business logic with the database layer. Creating `events` like `user [x] closed a project` is actually not the job of doctrine, but of your application. You should actually create separate business logic classes who are responsible for persisting data to your entities, which should not depend on which database your are using. You could create dao's for this. Then register an event listener in symfony, which will execute some code when the `onUserClosedProject`-event is called. You can pass the user and the event to that function.

Comment: I did not create early event, how to create event for this business logic ?

Comment: update my question

Answer (score 0):

Take into account that the prePersist and preFlush methods are within the Project class itself. In order to add it to your event's object you only need to use `$this`:

```
public function PrePersist(){
    if($this->getCurrentStatus() == self::STATE_TO_BE_INDEXED_IN_ELA_CLOSED_BY_CLIENT){
        $event = new CodeEvents();
        $event->setProject($this);
    }
}
```

Comment: But if in controller `$potentialClient = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
            ->getRepository('ArtelProfileBundle:Project')
            ->find($id);` and when `$event->setProject($this);` set exist project? Or how to create independent listener  ?

Answer (score 0):

In the title you asking about Symfony event listeners, but you actually using doctrine event listeners.

My notes here:

1, You will need to create a symfony2 event and fire that from your doctrine events. If you want to fire symfony2 events complicates the thing a bit, as you will need access to the framework event dispatcher, you will need to inject it to your LifeCycleEventListener.
So:

- create your own Symfony event for this status change
  http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher/introduction.html#creating-and-dispatching-an-event
- create a separate Doctrine entity event listener to your Project entity, where you inject the sf framework event dispatcher
- define it in the sf2 configuration
  http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineBundle/entity-listeners.html
- using the event dispatcher in your doctrine listener dispatch your status change event
- create your event subscriber or listener in symfony which will handle the status change event (same link as the first point).

2, I would consider checking if the status field changed at all, otherwise you will create a lot of CodeEvent() instances when any other property changes of the Project entity and the status is already 'closed_by_client'
See here:
http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-callbacks-event-argument

Comment: I try, but I do not have such a great experience to do it all, maybe some example very help for me

Comment: I would suggest for the time being to implement your logic in the doctrine entity listener, and don't go around the Symfony event listener. (Actually, you are already using an event system, if you are not willing to do any other  logic, I think it is sufficient to stay in that event system).

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment on your opening question but:

```php
public function PreFlush(LifecycleEventArgs $event){
}
```
The parameter type hint is wrong, this listener is on the entity, so it should be

```php
public function PreFlush(PreFlushEventArgs $event){
}
```

Comment: If using doctrine event `@ORM\PreFlush()` how to flush another entity, where get entity manager or how to flush ?

Comment: According to the documentation, it is safe to use $em->flush() in this event, so I suppose $em->persist($event), $em->flush() should do the trick.

Comment: do _not_ mix doctrine - which is nothing more then an ORM, and should be treated as such - with symfony or business logic. You even should not directly communicate with Doctrine in a controller, but rather through services. These services should handle persistent operations, and everything that comes with it. When a service, in example, updates one entity, it can update another non-related entity right away, or fire an event.

Comment: @giorgio I agree, but I'm afraid this will get him too far from his goal of a working code. I think he is not at that level yet.

Comment: @AndrasLaczi yeah I think you're right. Ok let's make it a bit easier, and still a bit cleaner :) Why do you need an event anyway? Can't you just in your controller (or wherever you do it) persist the `Project`, and right away do something like `if ( $user_closed_the_project ) { new Event('project_closed', $user)->persist(); }`? Easy does it, and you don't mixin business logic in doctrine!

Comment: @giorgio Thats also can do the trick. But if he just create a separate doctrine event listener class and hooks that in with Symfony2 configuration ( http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineBundle/entity-listeners.html ) thats a first step to decouple the logic from doctrine (if you want to drop doctrine you can hook on another event manager). Now, I think we managed to totally confuse him :D